# How to use the plugin "Encryptable Field" for unique fields on Strapi?

Tags: encryption, strapi

I've enabled the data encryption for Strapi using the plugin [Encryptable Field](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-encryptable-field) which is working well, the only issue is when I need to encrypt fields like email/username - they need to be unique but everytime a new record is inserted the encrypted data is different even for the same data, therefore the record is added again (duplicated).

```
"username": {
  "type": "customField",
  "options": {
    "hint": null
  },
  "customField": "plugin::encryptable-field.encryptable-field",
  "unique": true,
  "configurable": false,
  "required": true
},
"email": {
  "type": "customField",
  "options": {
    "hint": null
  },
  "customField": "plugin::encryptable-field.encryptable-field",
  "unique": true,
  "configurable": false,
  "required": true
}
```

How to fix it?